# warning: `label` of `value` is not same as `label` in Select options

Tags: typescript, antd

I am using antd `"antd": "^5.4.0"` select component as my ID Photo Maker size selector, this is the typescript code that render the selection looks like:

```
const renderPhotoTypeImpl = () => {
        const photoList: JSX.Element[] = [];
        if (photoType && photoType.length > 0) {
        photoType.forEach(item => {
            const pType = item.trim();
            if(pType && pType.length > 0) {
                const photoTypeContent = pType.split(',');
                const showText = photoTypeContent[0] + '(' + photoTypeContent[1] + 'cm *' + photoTypeContent[2] + 'cm)';
                photoList.push(
                    <Option key={uuid()} value={item} label={item}>
                        <Space>
                            {showText}
                        </Space>
                    </Option>);
                }
        });
        }
        return photoList;
    }
```

when I select the option in the UI, the Devtools console log shows error like this:

```
ract_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 Warning: `label` of `value` is not same as `label` in Select options. 
    at http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:48576:18
    at InternalSelect (http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:25769:18)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at GenPhoto (http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:1812:82)
    at ConnectFunction (http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:82788:114)
    at div
    at Home (http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:1166:88)
    at ConnectFunction (http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:82788:114)
    at RenderedRoute (http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:86460:5)
    at RenderErrorBoundary (http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:86408:5)
    at DataRoutes (http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:86829:5)
    at Router (http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:86938:15)
    at RouterProvider (http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:86777:5)
    at Provider (http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:82518:5)
o
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: Can you add Select component code? Looks like you are using fieldsNames prop in select or issue with label prop. You can check the source code for [rc-select](https://github.com/react-component/select/blob/master/src/Select.tsx#L273)